# How to call Class method in other method

Tags: php, oop, methods

I am try to call my public function in other function.first think I am new on object oriented so maybe my logic not correct but i am try.Here down i am showing what i have done.and what i want.

**config.php**

```
require('core.php');
$url_site = "http://www.mysite.com/musicjee/";
```

**core.php**

```
 class Core_musicjee

 {   

      public function link_main($url_site)

   {

          $http =$url_site; 
          echo $http;

   }

      public function insert_data()
      {


      echo "Main URL is" // there i want to call link_main($url_site) function ;

      }


}
 $core = new Core_musicjee;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with PHP's `$this` pseudo-variable.

From PHP Documentation:

`The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).`

core.php

```
    <?php
class Core_musicjee

 {   

      public function link_main($url_site)

   {

          $http =$url_site; 
          echo $http;

   }

      public function insert_data($url_site)
      {


      echo "Main URL is "; // there i want to call link_main($url_site) function ;
          $this->link_main($url_site);

      }


}

?>
```

Config.php

```
   <?php
      require('core.php');
      $url_site = "http://www.mysite.com/musicjee/";

     $core = new Core_musicjee();
     $core->insert_data($url_site);
   ?>
```

Comment: @AffanAhmad just modify that line. For Eg. `$this->link_main("http://bing.com/");` See my updated answer.

Comment: `$url_site` variable i am putting from `config.php` so just need to call function and this function replay me URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the class function in another function like this

```
public function insert_data()
{
   $this->link_main("YOUR URL");
}
```

You have to use `$this->` to call any function in another Class function.